# SVG linearGradient sharing def but with unique colour?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this or not.  What would ideally like is:

1. Define a common linearGradient in the 'defs' section of the DOM
2. Reference this in multiple 'circle' instances throughout the DOM using the fill attribute.

So far so good, this works fine, now using scripts I want to change the 'stop-color' attribute of the linearGradient but so it only effects an individual circle.  Is there any way to do this without having to have copies of the linearGradient for each instance?

Example below, I haven't posted the JS because that is the question.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" 
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
     xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" 
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
     xmlns:sodipodi="http://inkscape.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" 
     xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="lampbevel" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0">           
      <stop stop-color="#bfbfbf" offset="0" />           
      <stop stop-color="#404040" offset="1" />          
    </linearGradient>          
    <linearGradient id="lampcap" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">           
      <stop stop-color="#00ff00" stop-opacity="0.992188" offset="0" />           
      <stop stop-color="#000000" stop-opacity="0.988281" offset="1" />          
    </linearGradient>          
    <linearGradient id="lampspec" spreadMethod="pad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">           
      <stop stop-color="#000000" stop-opacity="0.996094" offset="0" />           
      <stop stop-color="#ffffff" stop-opacity="0.984375" offset="0.703125" />          
    </linearGradient>        
  </defs>
  <g id="lamp1" transform="translate(0,0) scale(0.05)">
    <title>Lamp 1</title>
    <circle id="lamp1_3" fill="#212121" stroke-width="17.5" stroke-linecap="round" cx="320" cy="240" r="196.125"/>
    <circle id="lamp1_7" fill="url(#lampbevel)" stroke-width="17.5" stroke-linecap="round" cx="319.252837" cy="239.999045" r="160" fill-opacity="0.64"/>
    <circle id="lamp1_8" fill="url(#lampcap)" stroke-width="17.5" stroke-linecap="round" cx="320.000535" cy="240.001698" r="150"/>
    <ecllipse id="lamp1_20" transform="rotate(-47.7626 249.18 168.124)" fill="url(#lampspec)" stroke-width="17.5" stroke-linecap="round" cx="249.179609" cy="168.124194" rx="75.675959" ry="44.402987"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: A code example will be helpful so we can see what you have tried and some context of what  your code looks like.

Comment: You will need multiple linear gradients.

Comment: That as I thought, pity